# Accessing all data in API response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm currently using the SDK to retrieve details on a group. Looking at the Group model, there are quite a few methods to display data.

When I `print_r()` the group, it returns a Group object with a protected _propDict property. The issue is, some of these aren't accessible via getters, for example:

```
Microsoft\Graph\Model\Group Object
(
[_propDict:protected] => Array
(
    [id] => XX-YY-ZZ
    [deletedDateTime] => 
    [classification] => 
    [createdDateTime] => 2019-04-18T15:09:57Z
    [creationOptions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team
            [1] => classAssignments
            [2] => ExchangeProvisioningFlags:2509
        )

    [description] => 
    [displayName] => Example Group
    [groupTypes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Unified
        )

    [mail] => test@example.com
    [mailEnabled] => 1
    [mailNickname] => ExampleGroup
    [onPremisesLastSyncDateTime] => 
    [onPremisesSecurityIdentifier] => 
    [onPremisesSyncEnabled] => 
    [preferredDataLocation] => 
    [proxyAddresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => SPO:SPO_ABCDE123456
            [1] => SMTP:test@example.com
            [2] => smtp:rest@example.onmicrosoft.com
        )

    [renewedDateTime] => 2019-04-18T15:09:57Z
    [resourceBehaviorOptions] => Array
        (
            [0] => HideGroupInOutlook
            [1] => WelcomeEmailDisabled
            [2] => ConnectorsDisabled
            [3] => SubscribeNewGroupMembers
        )

    [resourceProvisioningOptions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team
        )

    [securityEnabled] => 
    [visibility] => HiddenMembership
    [extension_ABC123_Education_ObjectType] => Section
    [onPremisesProvisioningErrors] => Array
        (
        )
)
)
```

So, for example, there is no current way to get the `deletedDateTime` or the `createdDateTime`. I would also like to get the `extension_ABC123_Education_ObjectType` value as well.

Is there an easy way of doing this using the Group model?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue is, some of these aren't accessible via getters

indeed, in that case the following approach could be considered to retrieve it via [`msgraph-sdk-php`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php).

Lets assume an extended data is exposed per Group and named `contoso_grpstatus`:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}?$select=displayName,description,contoso_grpstatus
{
    "displayName": "Group 123",
    "description": "Group 123",
    "contoso_grpstatus": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.ComplexExtensionValue",
        "Status": "Active"
    }
}
```

where `contoso_grpstatus` is a [schema extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups#1-view-available-schema-extensions)

```
  {
        "id": "contoso_grpstatus",
        "description": "Contoso - Group status",
        "targetTypes": [
            "Group"
        ],
        "status": "Available",
        "owner": "d1433ee1-b39b-49b0-b022-b1072a0aee38",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "Status",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ]
    }
```

then a custom Group class which extends `\Microsoft\Graph\Model\Group` could be introduced:

```
class GroupWithStatus extends \Microsoft\Graph\Model\Group{

    public function getStatus()
    {
        if (array_key_exists("contoso_grpstatus", $this->_propDict)) {
            return $this->_propDict["contoso_grpstatus"];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and finally Group properties (`DisplayName`) along with custom data (`contoso_grpstatus`) could be retrieved like this:

```
$url = "/groups/$groupId?\$select=displayName,contoso_grpstatus";
$group = $client->createRequest("GET", $url)
    ->setReturnType(GroupWithStatus::class)
    ->execute();

$displayName = $group->getDisplayName();
$status = $group->getStatus(); //custom data property
```